# Add an eventhandler to a button which is a radio converted slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, slider

I have utilised radios-to-slider plugin to convert a group of radio buttons to a slider bar. Here is the plugin I have used here to create this feature http://rubentd.com/radios-to-slider/ . This plugin works like a charm. I am interested to know which event handler I should use to load a function into radio converted slider buttons. I tried using `onclick()`, `onslide()`, `onmouseover()` as well. But little to no luck in loading a function. Could you please suggest which event handler can I make use of to load function to the radio buttons.

previous version:

onchange() event was working well when I called the function using below set of code

```
<div class="w3-display-container col-md-12 col-sm-10 col-xs-8" style="position:relative;top:1px;bottom:0;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(0)" checked>
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(1)">
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(2)">
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(3)">
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option5" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(4)">
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option6" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(5)">
                                    </label>

    </div></div></div>

Current code

<div id="radios">
                        <!--<input id="option1" name="options" type="radio">
                        <label for="option1">00:00:00 <br>secs</label>-->
                        <label for="option1">
                        <input id="option1"  name="options" type="radio" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(0)">
                        </label>

                        <label for="option2">
                        <input id="option2"  name="options" type="radio" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(1)">
                        </label>

                        <label for="option3">
                        <input id="option3" name="options" type="radio" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(2)">
                        <label for="option3"></label>

                        <label for="option4">
                        <input id="option4"  name="options" type="radio" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(3)">
                        </label>
</div>
```

What changes can I make it here to load datasegment function into my radio converted slider?

Comment: Inspect the HTML, figure out the element you want to add a listener to, and add the appropriate listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the radio buttons render after use functions of the plugin, try to use `on` instead of the traditional way. For example

```
$(document).on('change','your-radio-class',function(){
    //Your code here
})
```